# opensource php expert system for mySQL

Tags: php, open-source, decision-tree, expert-system, knowledge-management

I am looking for a open-source expert system (hopefully php). I would like something analogous to a binary decision tree, or some kind of yes/no solution to solving problems

Problem ---> Questions -----> Solution
RootNode---> Decision Nodes ----> Leaf Node

Something compatible with mySQL. Does anything exist?

Comment: An old question. But someone might find what I have here useful: [PhpExpertSystem](http://www.deadschool.com/phpexpertsystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first result on google: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexpertsystem/
I would suggest that you use prolog for that kind of stuff. It is much faster and easier.
You can call [SWI prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) from php. [check it](http://www.j-paine.org/dobbs/prolog_from_php.html)

Comment: Don't worry, there are so much cases even worse than this one :)

Comment: WOW, its gang up time! Look how many people jump up and wield there power and close the question down. I'm not sure how you got "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" from "Does anything exist?" - he he he  - i love coming to this forum and watch not only what you all just did, but when you all contest one another's answers to solutions. I wold much rather use Experts Exchange, but it cost money. So i just put up with you all

Comment: @user1598696 - im giving the the up and check mark just because you were civilized